# Bayes' rule, Balls transferred from urn1 to urn2

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

I know this question has been asked, but I did not find the answer satisfactory.

An urn contains 5 white and 4 black balls. 4 balls are drawn from this urn and put into another urn. From this second urn a ball is drawn and is found to be black and it is not replaced. What's the probability of drawing a white ball at the next draw.

If we call our events A: get a black on the first draw and B: get a white on the second:

$$P(B|A) = \sum_{i=1}^4P(B|E_i)P(E_i)$$ where $E_i$ is the probability that i black balls were put into urn 2 originally.

$$P(B|A) = \sum_{i=1}^4P(B|E_i)P(E_i) = \sum_{i=1}^3P(B|E_i)P(E_i) = P(B|E_1)P(E_1)+P(B|E_2)P(E_2)+P(B|E_3)P(E_3)$$

this is equal to: $${{3 \choose1} \over {3 \choose 1}}{{5 \choose4} \over {9 \choose 4}} + {{4 \choose2}{2 \choose1} \over {3 \choose 1}}{{5 \choose2} \over {9 \choose 4}} + {{1 \choose1}{4\choose3} \over {3 \choose 1}}{{5 \choose1} \over {9 \choose 4}} = ...$$

Is this the correct way to approach this question?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: $P(B|A) = \sum_{i=1}^4P(B|E_i)P(E_i)$ is clearly false, since the right hand side does not depend on the event $A$ at all.

Comment: Your answer must be wrong because is does not equal $\frac58$. Also have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1709285/75923).

Comment: I meant to write P(B|A|Ei), but this is reflected in the following math

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the linked answer, the second urn is not needed to solve the problem, in which case the answer is obviously 5/8. I wanted to arrive at the same answer via conditional probabilities (since the problem was in a chapter on the same subject). This is the solution:

Let A: event that the second is white, B: Event that the first is black, $E_i$: the event that i white balls were transferred.

$P(E_0) = {1\over126}$, $P(E_1) = {10\over63}$, $P(E_2) = {10\over21}$, $P(E_1) = {20\over63}$

$P(B) = P(B|E_o)P(E_0)...P(B|E_3)P(E_3) = {1\over126}*1+{10\over63}*{3\over4} + {10\over21}*{1\over2} + {20\over63}*{1\over4} = 4/9$

And $P(A\cap B) = {10\over63}*{3\over4}*{1\over3} + {10\over21}*{1\over2}*{2\over3} + {20\over63}*{1\over4}*1 = 5/18$

And to end: $P(A|B) = P(A \cap B)/P(B) = 5/8$.